# FFT Determining ultra low frequency processes using Python Numpy/Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, frequency-analysis

I am starting an analysis of low frequency datas(energy monitoring) I got from csv file.
I retrieve the datas (approximatly 12000 points but could be more) and I know that there is a data every minute.
This sampling rate is always the same.

When I plot the datas, it seemes like a recurring process (dayly, weekly and monthly). So I imagine that I should see ultra low frequency when I plot the FFT.

Here is my code sor far. I don't show you the part where i retreive the datas since it's not revelant.
I also added a lowpass filter to get a sinus like function.

```py
## DATAS x-axis is x
## DATAS y-axis is y
# Number of Points ie 12000 points
N = len(y)
# 1 Sample per minute
T = 1 / 60.0
# Lowpass cutoff frequency 
cutoff = 0.0001 

x = np.linspace(0, T * N , N) 
B, A = butter(4, cutoff / (T / 2), btype='low') 
filterdY = lfilter(B, A, y, axis=0)

# Generating FFT
Fourier = abs(scipy.fft(filterdY));
freqs = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(filterdY.size, x[1]-x[0])

pylab.subplot(311)
pylab.plot(x, y)
pylab.subplot(312)
pylab.plot(x, filterdY)
pylab.subplot(313)
pylab.plot(freqs,20*scipy.log10(Fourier),'x')
pylab.show()
```

The here is a screen-shot of the graphs I plot.
It shows a week of energy consumption and as you can see, 5 days are well defined (bigger values)
[image: ScreenShot of graphs]

I can't analyse the graph properly but if I add a second pure sine wave signal to y values and I don't filter the sum, I can retrieve the sine frequency from the FFT.
As a frequency of a daily process should be 1.0E-5 Hz, it is difficult to read the FFT.

How can i get this frequency ? Should I consider speeding up the original datas by 1.0E5 and then get a pic at 1Hz ?

Here is a pythonfiddle with the array of data stored into y variable : http://pythonfiddle.com/fft-test

Comment: is there a way you could provide sample data?

Comment: See my update : http://pythonfiddle.com/fft-test

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would play with sampling frequency. If you want to make some conclusions, suppose, on the scale of days why not set such sampling frequency that 1 Hz in resulting FFT would correspond to 1 oscillation per day rather than 1 oscillation per second? Following steps depend on your data.

P.S. I am not sure, because I can't see the whole script, but when you call butter and use cutoff / (T / 2) as an argument should't it be in Hz units? Because now it seems to be just  a number:

T = [1/s]; cutoff = [Hz] = [1/s]; => cutoff/(T/2) = [1/s]/[1/s] = 1

Comment: This was what I thought.
Concretely how can I proceed ?
Following your example, should I multiply the sampling rate by 1440 to get a 1Hz oscillation ?
The problem there is that my x-axis is directly created from this sampling rate. Then it will influence the sample spacing on this line  : 
`freqs = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(Fourier.size, x[1]-x[0])`
Then the x-axis of the FFT graph does not seem to be right.
Concerning the butter argument it's a normalize frequency (between 0 and 1) so it should be ok

Comment: @Marech yeah, I'd try multiplying the sampling rate by 1440, that's what I was talking about. Speaking of sample spacing, well, I'm not sure again but if changing sampling rate won't be enough you may try to resample your data set, that is, say, leave only _n_ points for each day so _n_ out of each 1440 (in numpy it's like: a.shape = (1440,) then a[::1440/ _n_] will leave only _n_ points out of initial 1440). Then you say that sampling rate is 1/ _n_ and then 1 Hz in FFT spectra will correspond to 1 oscillation per day. But in this case you will loose some data ofc, but it may not be essential